# using range based for loop for iterating on a sub range

Tags: c++11, for-loop, vector, range

Is it possible to loop over sub range using range based for loop ?

```
std::vector <std::string> inputs={"1","abaaaa","abc","cda"};
 
for (auto &it : new_vector(inputs.begin()+1, inputs.end()))
{
    // …
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Boost's `iterator_range`:

```
for (auto &it : boost::make_iterator_range(inputs.begin()+1, inputs.end()))
{
    cout << it << endl;
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UvnXXdRDZbGObq75)

Alternatively you could write your own wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such thing in the C++ standard library. However, you can define your own wrapper like this (requires at least C++ 11 - which should not be problem in 2021):

```cpp
template<typename Iter>
struct range
{
    Iter b, e;
    Iter begin() const { return b; }
    Iter end() const { return e; }
};
template<typename T>
auto slice(const T& c, std::size_t from, std::size_t to = -1) -> range<decltype(c.begin())>
{
    to = (to > c.size() ? c.size() : to);
    return range<decltype(c.begin())>{c.begin() + from, c.begin() + to};
}
```

And then you can use it:

```cpp
std::vector<int> items(100);
// Iterates from 4th to 49th item
for (auto x: slice(items, 4, 50))
{
    
}
// Iterates from 15th to the last item
for (auto x: slice(items, 15))
{
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

Long story short, you `#include <range/v3/view/subrange.hpp>` and change your `new_vector` to `ranges::subrange`. And that's it. [Demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/56naGxfe8).

### So

Given the name you imagine for this function, `new_vector`, ***maybe*** you think you need the entity on the right of `:` to be a `std::vector` or at least some type of container.

If that's the case, then change your mind, it's not needed. All that `:` wants from its "right hand side" is that it have `begin` and `end` defined on them, member or non member. For instance, this compiles and runs just fine:

```cpp
struct A {};
int* begin(A);
int* end(A);

struct B {
    int* begin();
    int* end();
};

int main()
{
    for (auto it : A{}) {}
    for (auto it : B{}) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not useful in C++11, but for those using C++20, `std::span` can make this pretty nice:

```
#include <span>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<std::string> inputs={"skipme", argv[0], "1","abaaaa","abc","cda"};
 
    for (auto& it : std::span(inputs).subspan(1, inputs.size() - 2)) {
        std::cout << it << '\n';
    }
}
```